# How to add RunListener and TestExecutionListeners when running with Cucumber

Tags: junit, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, spring-junit

Our current testing framework is running with *junit* + *spring* + *selenium*.
Our tests use both junit's `org.junit.runner.notification.RunListener`s and spring `org.springframework.test.context.TestExecutionListener`s.

This is how the test definition looks like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners(listeners = {MyTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/META-INF/spring/my-context.xml"})
public abstract class BaseAutomationTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {
}
```

My question is **where should I write the code that resides in the listeners when using Cucumber**?

Please note that **this code needs access to the spring's `ApplicationContext`**.